# Phonegap: possible to exclude certain files/folders from the apk?

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, apk

I'm using Phonegap in Eclipse (with the ADT plugin).

I have a big framework that I use for my normal HTML projects. This framework is full of js, css and graphics files.

For convenience I included the whole framework inside my Phonegap project, since I might need something from the framework later.

But when I build the apk, **all** files from the framework are included in the apk, which makes it bigger than 10MB. Most of the files are never used in the project, so I need to find a simple way to exclude those files/folders from the build.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

I've documented how to do this using build.xml on Coderwall:

https://coderwall.com/p/ogxpdg

I hope this helps somebody out!

- Gav

Comment: are you sure? Works fine for me... Here's a gist of its contents. Is your service provider perhaps blocking coderwall?

Comment: It is okay now, maybe it was a glitch in my network, sorry for the false flag.

Answer (score 0):

use the ant build process, remove the files before apk is made in the pre-compile method of the ant build process.

Comment: Thanks, already read about Ant, but I was hoping there was a more easy way, since I have no idea how to setup Ant yet.

Comment: search for it. check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793220/repackage-apk-file-to-contain-custom-assets-what-build-tool-to-use

Answer (score 0):

This **excludes** the whole `./www/app` directory **from the .apk** build:

`<property name="aapt.ignore.assets" value="&lt;dir&gt;app:" />`