# Android assets from linked folder

Tags: android, symlink

I would like to import into Assets folder an external directory, in which there are some files that I need to share across different platform distribution of the same app, basically Html files.

I've tried adding a **Linked folder** to android project from **New-> Folder-> Advanced**, using absolute or relative reference. But then

```
getAssets().open("folder")
```

Fails, with FileNotFound Exception.

I've tried also command line from assets folder:

```
ln -s ../../source_folder dest_folder
```

This creates a new "alias" folder into the filesystem, but Eclipse gets the folder not as a Linked resource but as a normal "Folder". I would go with this solution, but since we are a team of several developers sharing the same project, I believe the alias won't work on all systems, resulting that some files will be saved into the new "aliased" folder, others on the original folder.

In conclusion: is there anyone who came across the same problem?
Is there a way, for a team, to reference an external folder as an Android asset?

Comment: I'd say put the files you need in the folder instead of using different content for each developer, but I guess there is a very good reason for that.

Comment: I think you need to ant you your way out of this, there is a similar post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793220/repackage-apk-file-to-contain-custom-assets-what-build-tool-to-use

Answer (score 1):

If you are using android studio, you can add your folder to assets folder, like following:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        assets.srcDirs += 'your/folder'
    }
}
```

See here for detail:

- Android Studio:
  https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-tips.html#change-default-source-set-configurations
- Gradle:
  http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.api.AndroidSourceSet.html

Comment: What if I need not a folder, but a single file?