# Adding assets during the build

Tags: android, ant

The situation is such that I have some files that are in different repository than my Android app. I would like to add some of those assets to my apk's assets folder during the build by providing a build script with paths to those files. Also I would not want my repository to be modified.

Is it possible to do that with Ant?

Comment: Do you want to checkout them from repository?

Comment: Yes. They may either be already checked out or to be checked out during the build, doesn't matter. The main point is that they are in different repository and I can't add them all, so I need just a subset of the assets to put into the apk during the build.

Comment: Sounds simple. Just use `copy` task from ant.

Comment: I don't see how that is the solution. If I copy the files to assets directory, then my app's repository will be modified. Build procedure should not modify a repository.

Comment: Until you call something like add/commit your repository is still unchanged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understood correctly you don't want to modify folders content that is part of commited structure. So I see two variants do far:

1. Use build folder where you will copy code, assets, resources config files, etc. And remove/clean this folder after build. Sometimes it useful when you have several app versions like brands.
2. `apk` is `zip` so you could update it with assets (please review [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793220/repackage-apk-file-to-contain-custom-assets-what-build-tool-to-use)). But be careful if you're updating already signed `apk`

Comment: Yes, this is what I want. I am trying to hook up to Ant's -post-compile target to copy the assets and -post-package target to clean them up. However, as I have noticed, Eclipse does not build according to normal Android rules, or it ignores the setup of my build.xml. Maybe you happen to know how can I modify Eclipse's build, too?